# iOS 10 iscroll is very jerky

Tags: ios, cordova, iscroll

I am building a phonegap app and using iscroll to improve scrolling on both android and iOS but since upgrading to iOS 10 the scrolling has become very jerky(it does not follow my finger and when it catches up it scrolls really fast where you can not read anything).

Has anyone else had this issue or found a work around?

Update:

I have discovered that the if I remove the 'position:relative' from the body element in my css I can scroll smoothly but the scrollable window no longer grows correctly so my infinite scrolling does not work.

Also I am using iscroll-probe.js and I am not sure if that makes a difference.

Thanks